# Animate SVG Circle border like progress but one way and another

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Sry for my poor English, I'll try to describe what I need as best as possible. The jsFiddle will help you understand what I want : https://jsfiddle.net/8natrpqm/

```js
var circle = document.querySelector('.animated-circle--animated > .animated-circle__circle');
var ghostCircle = document.querySelector('.animated-circle--animated > .animated-circle__circle--ghost');

var radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
var circumference = radius * 2 * Math.PI;

circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
circle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;

ghostCircle.style.strokeDasharray = `${circumference} ${circumference}`;
ghostCircle.style.strokeDashoffset = `${circumference}`;

function setProgress(percent) {
  const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
  circle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}

function setGhostProgress(percent) {
  const offset = circumference - percent / 100 * circumference;
  ghostCircle.style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}


var progress = 0;
var ghostProgress = 0;

function animateProgress() {
  if (progress < 18) {
    progress++;
    setProgress(progress);

    setTimeout(animateProgress, 60);
  } else {
    animateGhostProgress();
  }
}

function animateGhostProgress() {
  if (ghostProgress < 18) {
    ghostProgress++;
    setGhostProgress(ghostProgress);
    setTimeout(animateGhostProgress, 60);
  } else {

  }
}

animateProgress();
```

```css
.circles {
  position: relative;
}

.animated-circle--fixed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.animated-circle--animated {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}

.animated-circle__circle {
  transition: 0.35s stroke-dashoffset;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.animated-circle__circle--ghost {
  z-index: 60;
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <svg class="animated-circle animated-circle--fixed" width="400" height="400">
        <circle class="animated-circle__circle" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" r="199" cx="200" cy="200" />
      </svg>

  <svg class="animated-circle animated-circle--animated" width="400" height="400">
        <circle class="animated-circle__circle" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" r="199" cx="200" cy="200" />
        <circle class="animated-circle__circle animated-circle__circle--ghost" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" r="199" cx="200" cy="200" />
    
        <circle class="circle-icon__circle" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="0" fill="red" r="15" cx="375" cy="110" />
      </svg>
</div>
```

I'd like to animate the border of a SVG circle, in a way that it goes until a point, then disappears progressively too. I'm using stroke-dashoffset, working fine for going from like 0 to 15, but I can't really find a way to go the opposite (meaning 15 stays the upper, but the down has to move up again to 0 to 15).

In the Fiddle, you'll see I tryed adding a ghost circle to overlap the first animated circle, but the result is kinda weird, like there is a graphical issue.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I cannot follow you in details, but the animation should animate between 0 and 15 (if we talk about a clock with 60 min for a full circle). The fixed point should be at 15 and then extend against 0.

As I see it your code is working, but you would like to be able to go back and fourth between 0 and 15.

I replaced your circle with a path because I can set the length of the path to make it easier to calculate the distance. Here I'm setting the dasharray based on the value of the range -- so, the only value that is changing is the first number in the array.

```js
document.forms.rangeform.range.addEventListener('change', e => {
  document.querySelector('#clock').style.strokeDasharray = `${e.target.value} 60`;
});
```

```html
<form name="rangeform">
  <input type="range" name="range" min="0" max="15" value="15">
</form>

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="none" stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="2"/>
  <path id="clock" pathLength="60" d="M50 10 a 40 40 1 1 0 1 0" fill="none" stroke="navy" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="15 60" stroke-dashoffset="-45" stroke-linecap="round" />
</svg>
```

Comment: plus 1 for ``pathLength``

Comment: That's working great in fact, but what if my want to have the same behavior, saying like between 15 and 60 ? I need the path to have a lower and an upper value, to move it around the circle, potentially with different sizes, but can't find how to it with your snippet

Comment: The two numbers that you need to control are 1) the first value in `stroke-dasharray` and 2) the value of `stroke-dashoffset`. In the example 15 and -45 is between 0-15 min, 30 and -30 will be 0-30 min, 45 and -15 will be 0-45 min.